# Replace numpy arrays of arrays with values

Tags: numpy, replace

I am trying to convert a numpy array of arrays. An example input is this:

```py
np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]], [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]]], np.uint8)
```

I want to replace all arrays with values `[0, 0, 0]` with `0` and the `[255, 255, 255]` with `255`. I want the final result to be in this format:

```py
np.array([[0, 255], [255, 0]], np.uint8)
```

The array will always have the above values but will be different size.

This is the code I created for doing this:

```py
array_list = []
for row in input_image:
    row_list = []
    for item in row:
        if np.array_equal(item, [0, 0, 0]):
            row_list.append(0)
        else:
            row_list.append(255)
    array_list.append(row_list)
output_image = np.array(array_list, np.uint8)
```

The above code is very slow for big arrays and I was thinking that there might be a way to do this directly with numpy, though I couldn't find a way. Do you have any suggestions for doing this more efficient?

Comment: What you show to a multi-dimensional array that you want to reduce along the third axis. This is a common operation. However, what do you want to do with other values such as `[1, 128, 32]`, or even `[255, 0, 0]`?

Comment: I don't have any other values because I am fixing it with this: `input_image = np.where(input_image != 255, 0, input_image)`

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that you don't have say `[255, 0, 255]` as a value. How do your plan on handling that?

Comment: If `a` is the input, you could use `a[:, :, 0]`, or `a[..., 0]`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't thought of that, though it won't be a problem on my application. All I want is to convert some black and white images to masks for OpenCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X_new = np.mean(X, axis=2)
X_new
array([[  0., 255.],
       [255.,   0.]])
```

Comment: Just take the mean across the third axis. Don't loop with numpy if it's at all avoidable.

Comment: And it's always avoidable. The only time I haven't been a able to find a fully vectorized solution was when I wanted to solve multiple simultaneous least squares problems with different coefficients.

Comment: @bkbilly Consider to accept the answer as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers